# DRF: cannot convert URL to instance using HyperlinkedIdentityField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I use a HyperlinkedIdentifyField to convert a url to an instance?

I have a couple of nested HyperlinkedModelSerializer:

```
class ChildSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('url', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'required': False}
        }

class ParentSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('url', 'child')
```

But this doesn't work:

```
>>> s = ParentSerializer(data={'child': {'url': '<valid url>'}})
>>> s.is_valid()
True
>>> s.validated_data()
OrderedDict([('child', OrderedDict())])
```

For whatever reason, `to_instance_value` from `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` doesn't retrieve the actual object.

So the obvious solution is to override this, but I cannot work out how to get the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` for `ChildSerializer` to return an internal value. I have a kludge that is working for now:

```
class ChildSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        pk = parse_pk_from_url(data['url'])
        return self.Meta.model.objects.filter(pk=pk).get()
```

But I feel like there *must* be a mechanism for retrieving objects from valid URLs that I'm missing here...

Comment: to_internals_value's traditional behavior is to return a native data type. however the way you figured out, is a common practice and an appropriate place to override and return an instance

Comment: @Dap is there a more direct way to go from url to instance, though?

Comment: might be misunderstanding your question here but I'd say no and what you are doing to serialize data to an instance is common practice so much that even  django rest serialize does this under the hood. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/b4db2dfacf283aa5a1f51ccf895222fbcf3709ec/rest_framework/relations.py#L256